# Batching render-triggering state updates caused by mobx reactions

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Assume in my mobx store I have three variables, each of which trigger extensive changes to rerender.

(so, for example:

- One contains the color to color all cells in a table.
- The other contains a case to convert all string content of cells in table to.
- The third is for the content of the cells.
  )

The user can trigger changes to one variable by itself, but can also trigger changes to 2 or 3 variables simultaneously.

I can set a reaction for each variable, but is there some way to set a reaction to changes of multiple variables at once (and block calling the individual reactions) so I can batch setState calls instead of re-rendering the table 3 times?

**Or is there some other way to ensure that react doesn't re-render until all mobx reactions are done?**

Comment: If you make changes inside `action` then re-render will only happen once, no matter how many variables you have changed.

Comment: marking a reaction as an action? how?

Comment: I did not said that, not mark reaction as an action. Change variables inside an action.

Comment: then that is not what I'm asking? after changing variables in an action, multiple reactions are triggered, one for each variable. each of those reactions includes a setState({}) that triggers a rerender. I want to batch the re-rendering somehow.

Comment: You probably using MobX incorrectly, reactions, setState, sounds like you are doing some extra work. Would be better if you could provide some minimal example on https://codesandbox.io/ for example.